# Rails render json: {} causing AJAX function to fall into error function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm having trouble with the success return of my controller function in my Rails app.

```
$.ajax
    url: '/create_signup'
    type: 'POST'
    dataType : 'json'
    data: { signup: { email: email }}

    success: ->
        # mixpanel
        hideEmailBar()



    error: (data) ->
            console.log data
            console.log "didnt work again"

            alert "There was an error signing you up. Please try again or contact Customer Support."
```

The posting is simple and works in the controller up to the point below. `result.code` equals 200 and then the `render json: {}` causes the AJAX call to fall into the error case.

I understand that `head :ok` doesn't work because the `dataType` for the AJAX call is `json`.

```
        result = HTTParty.post(url, options)
        p result.code

        if result.code.to_i == 200
            render json: {}
        else
            raise "Error Signing Up User"
        end
```

I'd love help in figuring out what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: head :no_content is also not working for me

Comment: I'm not sure i understood the problem, what is the error your are getting? When you say "_then the `render json: {}` causes the AJAX call to fall into the error case_", what error case are you referring to?

Comment: Could you show the contents of `result`?

Comment: It shouldn't matter as long as `code` is a 200. I'm successfully getting into the success case in the `if` block, it has to do with the json return

Comment: @ZackShapiro ajax `.error` takes three arguments, `xhr`, `status`, and `error`. It'd be helpful if you shared what those were.

Comment: @octopushugs here's an image of the printout of `xhr`, `status` and `error` in that order https://d2ppvlu71ri8gs.cloudfront.net/items/2x2I2b3t1n1l1l1Y3d1r/Screen%20Shot%202017-06-09%20at%208.13.31%20PM.png?v=2d9ed753

Note: nothing is printing for the 3rd parameter

Comment: The only other issue that is coming to mind: are you using UJS? You could be missing a CSRF token

Comment: I don't believe so. Just started this Rails project, code's all brand new. What's weird is that the model is created in my controller, my API call returns a 200 and for some reason this return causes my AJAX call to break...

Comment: One thing I found, it seems to be reloading the page when the AJAX call goes through. Maybe my issue is in that?

Comment: If the page is reloading then it's definitely not an AJAX call. Can you include your HTML?

Comment: Fixed it. I wrapped my input and button in a form tag before. I needed to do a `preventDefault` and watch the `submit` event on the form. Thanks for taking the time to try to help @octopushugs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue may be in not using a `respond_to` block. With your code you're just returning a JSON object without specifying the type, which jQuery requires for ajax calls. The response will still be a 200, it will just show up as a `parseError`.

Give this a shot:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render json: {}
  }
end
```

This specifies the response type as JSON, which should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That didn't fix the issue unfortunately.